# Javascript: filter an array of objects into two

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter, grouping

My array object is like below example.

```
list = [
{'name': 'test1', 'email': 'test1@gmail.com', 'ispin': true, 'updatedAt': 1540456416646}
{'name': 'test2', 'email': 'test2@gmail.com', 'ispin': false, 'updatedAt': 1540456416111}
{'name': 'test3', 'email': 'test3@gmail.com', 'ispin': true, 'updatedAt': 1540456412541}
{'name': 'test4', 'email': 'test4@gmail.com', 'ispin': false, 'updatedAt': 1540456414521}
]
```

I'm able to sort this array object like this.

```
return conversationList.sort((a, b) => {
  const firstTimestamp = a.lastMessage && a.lastMessage.createdAt ? a.lastMessage.createdAt : 0;
  const secondTimestamp = b.lastMessage && b.lastMessage.createdAt ? b.lastMessage.createdAt : 0;
  //Sort in DESC order
  return secondTimestamp - firstTimestamp;
});
```

Using the above code I'm able to sort an array of object in descending order.

Now, my requirement is first filter array based on **ispin key.** if ispin is set to true then I want to create new array object with key **pin** also in descending order and one more array with key **recent** in descending order.

So my final output should be like this.

```
{ 
  // first array object with key pin : filter by ispin:true and order by descending order
  pin: [
 {'name': 'test1', 'email': 'test1@gmail.com', 'ispin': true, 'updatedAt': 1540456416646}
 {'name': 'test3', 'email': 'test3@gmail.com', 'ispin': true, 'updatedAt': 1540456412541}
 ],
 // second array object with ket recent : order by descending order and records which has ispin false
 recent: [
 {'name': 'test2', 'email': 'test2@gmail.com', 'ispin': false, 'updatedAt': 1540456416111}
 {'name': 'test4', 'email': 'test4@gmail.com', 'ispin': false, 'updatedAt': 1540456414521}
 ]
}
```

Comment: I believe you can achieve this by `.reduce()` method. You can create a new array which contains the objects which have `isPin:true`, then sort that array as you did earlier.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  : I don't think this duplicate is a good one. I was writing an answer when you hammer closed the question, which was with a groupBy feature (using reduce as another comment mentioned). OP needs *grouping* here, not filtering, there can be much more better answer for this question than for the duplicate target.

Comment: ah right, I see it make no sense (and just realized it while looking at my answer). It should be `{ pin: [{}] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split your list depending on isPin value, you can do a grouping like this :

```js
list = [
  {'name': 'test1', 'email': 'test1@gmail.com', 'ispin': true, 'updatedAt': 1540456416646},
  {'name': 'test2', 'email': 'test2@gmail.com', 'ispin': false, 'updatedAt': 1540456416111},
  {'name': 'test3', 'email': 'test3@gmail.com', 'ispin': true, 'updatedAt': 1540456412541},
  {'name': 'test4', 'email': 'test4@gmail.com', 'ispin': false, 'updatedAt': 1540456414521},
]

const groupBy = (array, fn) => array.reduce((result, item) => {
  const key = fn(item);
  if (!result[key]) result[key] = [];
  result[key].push(item);
  return result;
}, {});

const result = groupBy(list, x => x.ispin ? 'pin' : 'recent');
console.log(result);
```

(note : groupBy inspired from https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4yi7e4/split_an_array_into_2_arrays_based_on_conditions/ ), and as said by the author of it, you can use `groupBy` from lodash instead, if you use this library.